# Extend and Embed Python (and NumPy) with C++ (and GSL): pass gsl_matrix to python and back

Tags: c++, python, numpy, gsl

my problem "should" be simple but I am still not able to solve it.

I am currently working on a project that requires some heavy computations (done in C++) and some post-simulations data analysis (done in Python).

However, now I am changing the main algorithm and I will need to "cycle" some computations back and forth from C++ and Python.
That is, I will need to move back and forth from C++ and Python a matrix of doubles.

In C++ the matrix of data is a "gsl_matrix" object while in python the same matrix is implemented as a "numpy array".

At the moment, I am running my C++ code, saving the matrix to file, reading it from python, writing it back to file and then opening it back again in C++ for further computations.

Since this is VERY inefficient, I would like to ask if somebody can give me an example on how to do it in a "clean" way.

I have been reading (and trying for 10 days) SWIG, Cython, Boost.Python and Boost.Numpy but I'm still not able to crack it.

Does anyone have a worked example to share?

Thanks!

Rene

Comment: How do you see things happening? Converting a `gsl_matrix` `struct` pointer to a `PyArrayObject` pointer using `PyArray_SimpleNewFromData` seems pretty straightforward, but how to handle everything around it depends very much on what/how you want things to happen.

Comment: well, the idea would be to have something live:
"
import numpy as np
import MYCPP as mycpp

DATA = np.loadtxt(...) # here DATA would be a TxN matrix
out = mycpp.run(DATA, params) # here out would be a Nx1 vector
"

In C++, DATA needs to be a gsl_matrix in order to work and the "out" vector returned from the C++ code will be a gsl_vector

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to implement yourself the wrapper, because you may use [pygsl](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pygsl/). If you really want to implement your own version, here is the routine from pygsl that might be worth to you

```
%{
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix_double.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix_complex_double.h>
%}

%include typemaps.i

// gsl_matrix typemaps
%typemap(in) gsl_matrix* %{
  PyArrayObject *_PyMatrix$argnum;
  gsl_matrix_view matrix$argnum;
  {
    _PyMatrix$argnum = (PyArrayObject*)
      PyArray_ContiguousFromObject($input, PyArray_DOUBLE, 2, 2);
    if (_PyMatrix$argnum == NULL)
      return NULL;
    matrix$argnum
      = gsl_matrix_view_array((double*)_PyMatrix$argnum->data,
                  _PyMatrix$argnum->dimensions[0],
                  _PyMatrix$argnum->dimensions[1]);    
    $1 = &matrix$argnum.matrix;
  }
%}
```

Comment: I am still not sure how to use this.
Anyway, I don't think pygsl is a solution. I don't need to call gsl functions, I need to be able to pass a gsl_matrix to my C++ program from python. I.e. I need to make my C++ program "seen" as a python module to send and return gsl_matrices.

Comment: I put this pygsl implementation code because it seems to be the way pygsl sends the python array to GSL ("(double*)_PyMatrix$argnum->data"). So, it seems the conversion to C/c++ gsl_matrix has to be somewhat similar to this.

Comment: I still have no idea of what to do with this.